# Expert modeler for forecast in R like in SPSS

Tags: r, spss, forecasting

In SPSS, there is good feature for time series, which is called expert modeler
here the screen.

[image: screen]
It chooses the best model,by it's R^2, Stationary R^2, RMSEA, MAE, MAPE in automatic mode.

Can R do that?

Here my data

```
          SERIES_G
JAN 1949    112
FEB 1949    118
MAR 1949    132
APR 1949    129
MAY 1949    121
JUN 1949    135
JUL 1949    148
AUG 1949    148
SEP 1949    136
OCT 1949    119
NOV 1949    104
DEC 1949    118
JAN 1950    115
FEB 1950    126
MAR 1950    141
APR 1950    135
MAY 1950    125
JUN 1950    149
JUL 1950    170
AUG 1950    170
SEP 1950    158
OCT 1950    133
NOV 1950    114
DEC 1950    140
JAN 1951    145
FEB 1951    150
```

Comment: Your answer is not about code is about opinion. But no, R cannot do exactly like SPSS.

Answer (score 2):

The `ets` (for exponential smoothing models) and `auto.arima` (for ARIMA models) functions included in the `forecast` package come close to what you are looking for. You'll have to manually specify under which (if any) constraints the models are to be estimated, but these functions will automatically select the 'best' model based on AIC and BIC values.

For more information, have a look at the package documentation and [this](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v027i03) publication by two of the authors of the `forecast` package.